# How to prevent Windows 7 from clearing the Start menu's Run command history

Tags: windows-7, command-line, start-menu

I have a Windows 7 Pro machine that won't maintain a record of all the commands I enter via Start -> Run. I have UAC disabled, but there is still some setting that's wiping out that list right after I enter a command. How can I tell the OS to preserve the command history?

Comment: This sort of question would be better suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to get the recent items in the Run command to be kept by double-clicking the Start Menu, Properties, Start Menu tab and checking "Store and display recently opened programs in the Start menu".

Comment: That worked. I had that option unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
Start_JumpListItems

This is the recent opened programs list, check to make sure this number is set to something more then say 0, it can be set as high as 60.

This also sets the recent programs list in the start menu.

Also make sure you are not nuking it via group policy. (gpedit.msc)

Comment: I didn't have that value in my registry so I added it. It does control the number of items in the Start menu, but doesn't seem to affect saving the command line history. There isn't any special group policy being applied, but maybe there's one that by default is clearing the Run history. Any idea what that policy might be called?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and there was an old GPO clearing out my run command history.

In the GPO editor it's under `User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar`. The policy is called "Clear history of recently open documents on exit".

"Disabled" or "Not Configured" will keep your Recent Items and Jumplists intact.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. What is a GPO?

Comment: @Kazark GPO is short for Group Policy Object. It's the settings that admins can use to restrict or configure a group of computers.